# Google Assistant not working after integration with IFTTT

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, ifttt

I connected IFTTT with Google Assistant in order to test some custom commands.

The idea was to tell the assistant:

> Ok Google, this is, John

And I wanted the Assistant to reply, saying:

> Hi John, nice to meet you!

[image: Google Assistant IFTTT issues]

**Note:** this is an example of the command I created. As I said before the original command was deleted (around November 2018) in IFTTT the same day I disconnected my account from the service.

It worked as expected but then I noticed that all the core commands were replaced by the custom command created in IFTTT.

For example, simple commands like:

> Ok Google, what time is it?

Returned:

> Hello ***what time is it***, nice to meet you!

Since then (November 2018) I have tried all sort of things:

- I have deleted the custom commands in IFTTT
- I have disconnected IFTTT from my Google Assistant Account
- Deleted the cache in Google App in my android handset
- Delete the history of voice commands at https://myactivity.google.com
- Restored Google Home device to factory settings
- Looked into https://developers.google.com/actions/ to see if there was a way to DEBUG or RESTORE my Assistant. Unfortunately this only allows me to create apps to be used with the Assistant.

But nothing seems to fully restore the Assistant's behaviour to where it was before the integration with IFTTT.

**Update:** After all the things I have tried it seems to be improved (although not totally fixed).

I mean, now it does not reply with the custom command created in IFTTT but instead it replies saying ***Sorry I cannot process that request***

For example, when asking simple commands like thew the following:

> Ok Google, what time is it?
>
> Ok Google, what day is today?
>
> Ok Google, what can you do?

It replies saying:

> Sorry I cannot process that request.

This ***only happen in the language I created the custom command for***. If I ask the same question **in another language it works fine**.

Also, this ***only happen in the Google Account I used to created the custom commands.*** **If I create a new Google Account** and activate the Assistant in there **it works fine** in any language.

### Same issue reported in Google forums

- https://support.google.com/assistant/thread/252800?hl=en
- https://support.google.com/assistant/thread/662913?msgid=662913

### So here are the questions:

- Is there a way to DEBUG/Fix this issue? (apart from creating a new Google Account which is my last resource)
- Is there a way to restore the Google Assistant to its defaults?

**Update2:** I recently noticed (maybe I am going mad) that if I replace the word `what` with something else, the commands actually work.

For example if I say:

> Ok Google, <s>what time is it</s> tell me the actual time?
>
> Ok Google, <s>what day is today</s> which day is today?
>
> Ok Google, <s>what can you do</s> how can you help me?

I get the right response from the assistant.

Comment: Downvote the question without giving a reason why?

Comment: I still have my Google Assistant broken :(
Anybody out there experiencing a similar issue?

Comment: This exact thing happened to me too. I've tried everything. Still broken months later. "Sorry I cannot process that request.". My google account is borked.

Comment: Mine is still broken. Maybe one day we will find a way to fix it